# Is it possible to switch to a better university for PhD after completing a Masters in computer science?

Tags: phd, computer-science, united-states

Is possible to get into a "better" university for PhD after doing an MS in a relatively low grade school in the United States? If so, what kind of profile is expected during admission?

Comment: Of course it's *possible*.  (Proof: I did it.)  The kind of profile you need for admission to a strong PhD program has already been addressed *many* times on this site ([two](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/9877/65) [examples](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/10283/65)).

Comment: Should low grade be low-grade?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to re-take some coursework, because there may be restrictions on transferring graduate coursework from a graduate program to another, and you are going to need a high masters GPA as well as some research experience for this move to be successful.

Comment: @user12169 is correct, at least within the US. Some but not all of my masters coursework was recognized by my PhD department.